# In a custom lobby, is there a way to remove the round time limit?

Tags: valorant

There's loads you can change in a custom lobby. Infinite abilities, no cooldowns, infinite money, etc.

So I like just trying some grenade throws see where they land, or bow beacon shots to see how I could reveal something from the other end of the map.

Only thing annoying, every 2 minutes you get put back to spawn because the round ended.

So is there a way to change the round timer in a custom lobby, to make it, for instance, infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable cheats, there's an option to pause the timer
[image]